# SQL table: How can I show a table built from another SQL table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

My task is to show on screen a table built by SQL and PHP but the SQL table's structure is not as I need.

In the source table:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║   User    Date     Attr    Val  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╣
║   alex    1.2.3      A      523 ║
║   alex    1.2.3      b      5   ║
║   alex    1.2.3      c      12  ║
║   mark    2.3.4      A      244 ║
║   mark    2.3.4      b      0   ║
║   mark    2.3.4      c      88  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝
```

Every user appears 3 times with the same date and the only thing that changes is the attr and val, but the table I need to show is per user and looks like this:

For - alex:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║ Date   A    B    C  ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ 1.2.3  523   5   12 ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

(only one row for every date)

My task is to build a system that will automatically take data from the source SQL table from the DB and create the up to date table.
I built the table itself but have no idea how to insert automatically the data into it.

Thanks !

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is your goal to select records from your table and display them as shown, or is it to insert records?

Comment: Will there always only be one row per person per date per attribute?

Comment: The final table will always show to the user his A , B and C values for every day. today he sees his A, B , C details and the next row will contain the next day and his data.

Comment: My goal is to only select records from a table given to me from other server and to display them in my website in the second table. The table I receive looks like the first table in my question. First table is an SQL table and the second one is an HTML table that I must display in the website. I use MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline selects with corresponding where clauses. Following code is written for mssql server but it is possible that it can work in mysql too(I haven't write anything for mysql for ages)

```
SELECT User, Date (SELECT Val FROM SourceTable AS ST1 WHERE ST1.Attr='A' AND ST1.User = SourceTable.User AND ST1.Date = SourceTable.Date) AS A, (SELECT Val FROM SourceTable AS ST2 WHERE Attr='B' AND ST2.User = SourceTable.User AND ST2.Date = SourceTable.Date) AS B, (SELECT Val FROM SourceTable AS ST3 WHERE Attr='C' AND ST3.User = SourceTable.User AND ST3.Date = SourceTable.Date) AS C FROM SourceTable
```

You can use joins as well similar to this.